# It seems to me it is not necessary to declare inheritance between parameters in a generic class

Tags: c#

QUESTION EDITED.

Im learning basics of C# now.
Im learning from a website, and they say that you can do this to inherit between A,B,C:

```
public class Classs<A, B, C> where A : B where B : C
{

}
```

I wrote this in Main method:

```
Classs<Class1,Class2,Class3> trida = new Classs<Class1, Class2, Class3>();
```

`Class1`, `Class2`, `Class3` are classes that I defined. For this code to work without error, I had to declare inheritance when defining Class1, Class2:

I wrote `Class1 : Class2` and `Class2 : Class3`

SO MY QUESTION IS:

Why should I declare `where A : B where B : C` in `Classs`. If I declare field `Class1 myfield;` in `Classs`, then the inheritance in that field to `Class2` works even without `where A : B where B : C`.

Comment: Yes, it will work without that as well. It will depend on your requirement. If you have any dependency in generic code which require `A : B` & `B : C` then `where A : B where B : C` will make sure that whenever you create object it will enforce `Class1, Class2 & Class3` to follow required condition & generic code work without error.

Comment: I'm not sure generic constraints can be considered as c# basics. IMHO, Basics is understanding simple syntax, loops, conditions, classes, structs, interfaces... Generics is Intermediate level at best.

Comment: In a way this is a self-answering question. Why should you declare the class that way? Because you need three generic arguments - A, B, and C. B must implement C, and A must implement B. If that is what you need then that it what you should declare. If it's not what you need, then the answer is that you shouldn't. It's not really answerable because it's hypothetical. The point is just to understand what the generic constrains mean, what they allow. But in real life I don't see the need for anything like this very often. They could make the information a little clearer and more practical.

Answer (score -1):

It is required when you want to cast the types to the classes/interfaces they inherit from

```
class Backpack<T1,T2,T3> {
   T1 Element;
   T1 GetAsT1 => Element;
   T2 GetAsT2 => (T2)Element; // CS0030
   T3 GetAsT3 => (T3)GetAsT2; // CS0030
}


class BetterBackpack<T1,T2,T3> where T1:T2 where T2: T3 {
   T1 Element;
   T1 GetAsT1 => Element;
   T2 GetAsT2 => (T2)Element; // works fine
   T3 GetAsT3 => (T3)GetAsT2; // works fine
}
```

By itself it might look pretty stretched, but if it's used with more precise constraints (like `T2 : SomeGenericClass<T3>`) it might be useful.

```
class BetterBackpack<T1,T2,T3> where T1:T2 where T2: SomeGenericClass<T3>
{
   T1 Element;
   T1 GetAsT1 => Element;
   T2 GetAsT2 => (T2)Element; // works fine
   IEnumerable<T3> GetAsT3 => Element.GetThree(); // works fine
}

class SomeGenericClass<T> {
   T elem;
   public IEnumerable<T> GetThree() => new List<T>{elem, elem, elem};
}
```